# PHP Convert Full Date To Short Date

Tags: php, regex, date

I need a PHP script to loop through all .html files in a directory and in each one find the first instance of a long date (i.e. `August 25th, 2014`) and then adds a tag with that date in short format (i.e. `<p class="date">08/25/14</p>`).

Has anyone done something like this before? I'm guessing you'd explode the string and use a complex case statement to convert the month names and days to regular numbers and then implode using `/`.

But I'm having trouble figuring out the regular expression to use for finding the first long date.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You would probably receive fewer downvotes if you showed what you had tried so far

Comment: Thanks for the advice...relatively new to stackoverflow and didn't realize people would penalize me without even asking for clarification or additional details. In any case, I appreciate your help and advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it in semi-pseudo-code...

1. Loop through all the files using whatever floats your boat (`glob()` is an obvious choice)
2. Load the HTML file into a `DOMDocument`, eg

   ```
   $doc = new DOMDocument();
   $doc->loadHTMLFile($filePath);
   ```
3. Get the body text as a string

   ```
   $body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body');
   $bodyText = $body->item(0)->textContent; // assuming there's at least one body tag
   ```
4. Find your date string via this regex

   ```
   preg_match('/(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) \d{1,2}(st|nd|rd|th)?, \d{4}/', $bodyText, $matches);
   ```
5. Load this into a `DateTime` object and produce a short date string

   ```
   $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('F jS, Y', $matches[0]);
   $shortDate = $dt->format('m/d/y');
   ```
6. Create a `<p>` `DOMElement` with the `$shortDate` text content, insert it into the `DOMDocument` where you want and write back to the file using `$doc->saveHTMLFile($filePath)`

Comment: this is much more comprehensive, +1

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. The preg_match and date formatting code in steps 4 and 5 was precisely what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I incorporated the helpful response above into what I already had and it seems to work. I'm sure it's far from ideal but it still serves my purpose. Maybe it might be helpful to others:

```
<?php
$dir = "archive";
$a = scandir($dir);

$a = array_diff($a, array(".", ".."));

foreach ($a as $value) {

    echo '</br>File name is: ' . $value . "<br><br>";

    $contents = file_get_contents("archive/".$value);

    if  (preg_match('/(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) \d{1,2}(st|nd|rd|th)?, \d{4}/', $contents, $matches)) {

        echo 'the date found is: ' . $matches[0] . "<br><br>";

        $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('F jS, Y', $matches[0]);   
        $shortDate = $dt->format('m/d/y');

        $dateTag = "\n" . '<p class="date">' . $shortDate . '</p>';

        $filename ="archive/".$value;
        $file = fopen($filename, "a+");

        fwrite($file, $dateTag);
        fclose($file);

        echo 'Date tag added<br><br>';

    } else {

        echo  "ERROR: No date found<br><br>";

    }
}
?>
```

The code assumes the files to modify are in a directory called "archive" that resides in the same directory as the script.

Needed the two different `preg_match` lines because I found out some dates are listed with the ordinal suffix (i.e. August 24th, 2005) and some are not (i.e. August 24, 2005). Couldn't quite puzzle out exactly how to get a single `preg_match` that handles both.

**EDIT:** replaced double `preg_match` with single one using `\d{1,2}(st|nd|rd|th)?` as suggested.

Comment: Just use `\d{1,2}(st|nd|rd|th)?`

Comment: Ahh...that's it. I was trying all these things with `?:` and `?!` before `st|`. I owe you again, corrected my solution. Glad there are people like you out there.